# connecting panel mount switches to PCB

Tags: pcb, switches

I have a set of panel mount switches I'd like to connect - via cables - to a pcb.

The pcb won't have any components on it, it will just be a wiring loom. the concept is that having the complexity on the board will improve quality.

There's a mixture of DPDT, 3PDT and 4PDT switches, with a total of 60 connections required.

The switches I've sourced have solderlugs, like [50212LX](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/switchcraft-inc/50212LX/SC1821-ND/1642037) from Switchcraft Inc.

Is there a way to achieve this other than hand soldering each connection?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you have already chosen switches with solder lugs, you have little alternative but to hand-solder them to wires.

One alternatives is switches with PCB pins, which go directly into a board. This can make alignment with the panel difficult, so the technique there is to fit the switches, then push the PCB on, then solder the PCB. It does require that the panel be designed with a board in mind, so all switches on the same plane, not too far from each other, nothing big between them to foul the PCB, though board cut-outs can solve this.

Another alternative is switches with blade connectors. You can buy ready-crimped wires with connectors that push-fit onto the switches. You could mount blade connectors to the PCB as well, and push on wires with a connector each end.

Another alternative is switches with 0.1" pin grids for terminals. These would connect with IDC connectors and flat cable, though there are quite low voltage and current limits for this type of connector.

As Hearth pints out, you can also get switches with screw terminals.

Comment: You can get switches with screw connectors too, can't you?

Comment: thanks. I don't think it's feasible for my usage to have the switches directly on the pcb. It's clear I'll have to investigate what other connector formats are available on these switches.

Comment: Also the pin grid would be awesome, but I suspect it will be hard to source switches with the same physical characteristics

Comment: @xeroks awesomeness abounds. I clicked on the link to your switch. Then I clicked (at the top) slide switches (results 3884), then filter on 4PDT (results 92) then filter on 3A (results 10), then sort on termination PC pin (got 6, of which 5 are panel mount). [Here's one](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/cw-industries/GF-342-0057/CWI384-ND/4089898). You should get used to using digikey's parametric search.

Comment: The digikey search is - I find - difficult to use, especially if you don't exactly know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest wires like [these](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/molex/0797580011/WM15222-ND/6187843).

Cut them in half, solder the cut side to the switch, plug the other side into "crimp housings" that then plug onto male pins on your board.

Or use male pins to into female headers on your board.

I get mine from www.Pololu.com, you can easily (compared to Digikey) find wire with male-male terminations, or female-female, or male-female, in different lengths, or just connectors to crimp on to make your own, and a wide selection of crimp housings. 1x1, 1x2, ... 1x longer, 2x2, 2x3, ... 2x longer.

Comment: thanks, that's a great suggestion. Are those crimped housing connections secure enough for production usage? And a great website, it looks way easier to use (for a noob) than digikey.

Comment: Oh, if you want 'secure enough' then look at the the connectors at the friction lock headers, housings, and crimp pins here  https://www.peconnectors.com/friction-lock-hdrs-housings/ They are keyed and have a little lip on the headed that holds the housing.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I think of at the moment, but it's a little bit expensive and suitable only for large production: Create one PCB for each switch or for each group of switches which can be positioned reasonably close to each other to fit on a signle PCB, then add a ribbon cable connector to the PCB with the required number of wires. Can be simple 2.54 or 1.27 pin headers.
This would require designing several PCBs and have the switches and the headers soldered preferably at a factory. 
It may not be efficient if every switch is separated from the others. You can also design an "universal" PCB, one board, which could fit several switches or switch combinations. Kimiting the number of different PCBs.

Soldering everything manualy would take a lot of time. Yet even manualy that would be faster and easier to solder each switch pin on a PCB than soldering each wire to each switch pin.

Other than that I see only this solution: PCB terminals to clip the wires on, like this one.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/100pcs-6-3-Inserts-Plug-Spring-Terminal-250-PCB-Solder-lug-DJ611-6-3-thickness-0/32822493330.html?spm=a2g0s.13010208.99999999.266.30453c00wu0Ad6

Comment: I'll have to look further afield to source some alternative switches if i want to avoid soldering.  I suspect I'll just have to knuckle down!

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 switches which could be directly compatible with 2.54 mm ribbon cable or cable connectors.
If they are not too small for your application.

[1/](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/SA-H251A-single-tripod-two-tranches-of-2-54-pin-toggle-switch-slide-switch-6MS1/32474016791.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.118.1e1a44b6TP8yLL&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10065_10068_319_317_10696_10084_453_10083_454_10618_10307_10820_10821_537_10303_10302_536_10902_10059_10884_10887_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_6,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=9e1c2f56-6a77-422b-a746-08f184f8e336-19&algo_pvid=9e1c2f56-6a77-422b-a746-08f184f8e336)

[2/](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/60/ss-1280350.pdf)

[3/](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/26/PCB-slideswitches-serie-NK-1511073.pdf)